# В файл JSON записывается только последний словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу спарсить сайт. Но в файл JSON записываются не все 60 словарей ,а только последний последний

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('')
html = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser'

news_dict = {}
for el in html.select('.news> p> a '):
    news_dict = {}
    el_name = el.text
    el_href =el.get('href')

    news_dict = {
        'Приправа': el_name,
        'ссылка': el_href
    }

with open('spice.json', 'a') as file:
    json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну, наверное, правильно будет так:

```
news_dict = []
for el in html.select('.news> p> a '):
    el_name = el.text
    el_href =el.get('href')

    news_dict.append({
        'Приправа': el_name,
        'ссылка': el_href
    })
```

У вас всё-таки **список** словарей должен быть. И не надо его очищать каждую итерацию цикла.